# Literal does not match format string error When calculating the difference between two dates in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, oracle11g

I want to calculate the difference between two dates, and get the day difference between these dates in Oracle.
Here is my code:

```sql
Select To_Date(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD','nls_calendar=persian'))- TO_Date(TO_CHAR(SHF_Date))
from DtTable
```

But I get this error:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string for case statement

Comment: `SYSDATE` (and apparently also `SHF_Date`) returns a `DATE` value, never use `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a `DATE`

Answer (score 3):

`sysdate` is already a date, and `shf_date` also seems to be one. You don't need any conversion here, and can subtract them directly:

```sql
SELECT sysdate - SHF_Date FROM DtTable
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. SHF_Date  is Shamsi Date. for example : '1399/12/05' and Its format is different from sysdate format.

Comment: I should convert sysdate to shamsi date.

Comment: @n.e What is the [Oracle data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html) of the `shf_date` column?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson it is DATE.

Comment: @n.e That's great! Then it doesn't have a format. Formats are only applied when you display dates and numbers etc. You can display the same value in any format you like, just as you can display the same number as `1000`, `1,000` or `1e3`.  Mureinik's answer should work fine and return the number of days since `shf_date`. Doesn't it?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson  No,it doesn't work, because sysdate is : 18/04/2021 01:17:09 , but shf_date is: for example : 1398/10/05 and  when run SELECT sysdate - SHF_Date FROM DtTable, I get 'Invalid Number' error.

Comment: sysdate is : DD/MM/YYYY  but shf_date is : YYYY/MM/DD

Comment: @n.e If sysdate and shf_date appear differently formatted when you query them without any formatting (no `to_char`, `to_date` etc) then shf_date cannot be an Oracle `DATE`. Most likely it is a `VARCHAR2`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your statement

```
Select To_Date( TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD','nls_calendar=persian'), 'YYYY/MM/DD')- TO_Date(TO_CHAR(SHF_Date, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'YYYY/MM/DD') from DtTable;
```

But it does not make any sense.

Use it in this way

```
Select sysdate - hire_date from employees;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I should convert sysdate to shamsi date, because SHF_Date  format is shamsi date.

Comment: @n.e how is the column `SHF_Date` defined? Is it `DATE`, `VARCHAR2` or something else?

Comment: it is date. for example: 1399/05/01

Comment: @n.e refer to this link to know more about the Date data type. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm Date is not stored as you see when you fetch them. Date is store in seven different components in the Oracle database. Century, Year, Month, Day, Hour, Hour, Minute, Second and formated when you fetch them using NLS_DATE_FORMAT or user defined format.

Answer (score 2):

Storage format and display format are two different things. We let Oracle *store* data using its own internal format, which for `DATE` columns is a 7-byte binary value that is not human-readable.

How you choose to *present* the values in a report or application is another thing - for example, you could display the same number as `1000`, `1,000` or `1e3`, or display the same date as `2021-04-18` or `Sunday 18th April`. This is not related to how you store it. You cannot store any preferred display format. You have to handle the display format when you query it or in your application.

Also, in Oracle date arithmetic, subtracting one date from another gives a number of days, so trying to query `to_date(date2 - date1)` will never work, because how can it convert a number of days like 270 into a date?

```
create table dttable (shf_date date);

insert into dttable (shf_date)
values (to_date('1399/05/01','YYYY-MM-DD', 'nls_calendar=Persian'));
```

(Notice the definition of `shf_date` as an Oracle `date`. Is that how it is in your table?)

```
select to_char(shf_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'nls_calendar=Gregorian') as shf_date_gregorian
     , to_char(shf_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'nls_calendar=Persian') as shf_date_shamsi
     , trunc(sysdate - shf_date) as days_since_shf_date
from   dttable;

SHF_DATE_GREGORIAN   SHF_DATE_SHAMSI DAYS_SINCE_SHF_DATE
-------------------- --------------- -------------------
2020-07-22           1399-05-01                      270
```

Comment: @William Roberston Thanks William. I have to check the difference between these dates for the where clause. I run this code: select trunc(sysdate - shf_date)  from  dttable; but I get 'Invalid number' error.

Comment: @n.e - then `shf_date` is not actually a `date` column, sounds like you're storing it as a string. Add the table definition (e..g from `describe dttable`) and sample data to your question.

Comment: @William Roberston so how can I calculate subtracting sysdate and shamsidate?

Comment: @n.e What differences are there between my example and yours? If you copy and paste my example (perhaps using a different name for `dttable` if you already have a table with that name) do you get the same results? Can you make your own example similar to mine and add it to your question, starting with `create table` then `insert` then `select`? Or, create a demo on [db-fiddle](http://www.db-fiddle.com) or [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) (choosing Oracle)?

Comment: @Alex Poole Thanks for reply. shf_date column has changed to Varchar2(10).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson shf_date column has changed to Varchar2(10). Sorry, I thought it is date.

Comment: @n.e this is why it's always a good idea to include a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem when asking a question. It also shows the advantages of choosing the correct datatype when designing the table.

Answer (score 1):

Although you've said several times that `shf_date` is a date, you've also said things like:

> sysdate is : DD/MM/YYYY but shf_date is : YYYY/MM/DD

> I run this code: select trunc(sysdate - shf_date) from dttable; but I get 'Invalid number' error.

Which means it is not a date, but is stored as a string. So, you need to convert that string to a date, in Gregorian calendar, so that actual date can be compared with sysdate.

Modifying and expanding William's example:

```
select sysdate as sysdate_date
     , to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'nls_calendar=Gregorian') as sysdate_gregorian
     , to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'nls_calendar=Persian') as sysdate_shamsi
     , shf_date as shf_date_string
     , to_date(shf_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'nls_calendar=Persian') as shf_date_date
     , to_char(to_date(shf_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'nls_calendar=Persian'), 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'nls_calendar=Gregorian') as shf_date_gregorian
     , to_char(to_date(shf_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'nls_calendar=Persian'), 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'nls_calendar=Persian') as shf_date_shamsi
     , trunc(sysdate - to_date(shf_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'nls_calendar=Persian')) as days_since_shf_date
from   dttable;
```

```
SYSDATE_DATE | SYSDATE_GREGORIAN | SYSDATE_SHAMSI | SHF_DATE_STRING | SHF_DATE_DATE | SHF_DATE_GREGORIAN | SHF_DATE_SHAMSI | DAYS_SINCE_SHF_DATE
:----------- | :---------------- | :------------- | :-------------- | :------------ | :----------------- | :-------------- | ------------------:
18-APR-21    | 2021-04-18        | 1400-01-29     | 1399/05/01      | 22-JUL-20     | 2020-07-22         | 1399-05-01      |                 270
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=796d5d91f397d361ed25138d41fd3aba)

If you want to use this in a filter then you can do:

```
where trunc(sysdate - to_date(shf_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'nls_calendar=Persian')) = 270
```

or whatever comparison you need to perform.